# Accelerometer Issue

Tags: javascript, rotation, accelerometer

I'm developing a Car Racing Game and I'm stuck on Accelerometer.
I want to control my car with both TouchInput  and Accelerometer.
Touch Input is working fine, but i have problem with Accelerometer.

I used below Script from Script reference:-

```
       {
        var dir : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

    dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
    dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;

    // clamp acceleration vector to unit sphere
    if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        dir.Normalize();

    // Make it move 10 meters per second instead of 10 meters per frame...
    dir *= Time.deltaTime;

    // Move object
    transform.Translate (dir * speed);
           }
```

But, this Only slide my Car into x and z Direction and doesn't work properly (Turn)as it does in Touch Input.

Please help me on this. I'm stuck on this since 2 days.